# How to use one machine for deploy 2 project in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

### Visual Studio Team Service.

I am using a machine for continuous deployment and everything is OK for first project.
But in second project, when I add agent to same(previous) machine, deployment was failed with this error:

> Unable to deploy to the target 'WIN-XXXXXX' as the target is offline.

How to use one machine for deploy 2 project in VSTS?

**EDIT**:(Add Log)

```
[2017-09-19 14:35:17Z INFO RSAEncryptedFileKeyManager] Loading RSA key parameters from file C:\vstsagent\A2\.credentials_rsaparams 
[2017-09-19 14:35:18Z INFO RSAEncryptedFileKeyManager] Loading RSA key parameters from file C:\vstsagent\A2\.credentials_rsaparams 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'work': '_work' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Remove work from Arg dictionary. [2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO ConfigurationStore] Saving agent settings. 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO ConfigurationStore] Settings Saved. 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: 2017-09-19 14:35:20Z: Settings Saved. 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'runasservice': 'True' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO ConfigurationManager] Configuring to run the agent as service [2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'machinegroup': 'False' [2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'deploymentgroup': 'True' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'windowslogonaccount': '' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO PromptManager] ReadValue 
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO Terminal] WRITE: Enter User account to use for the service (press enter for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) >  
[2017-09-19 14:35:20Z INFO Terminal] READ LINE 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z INFO Terminal] Read value: '' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z INFO PromptManager] Falling back to the default: 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z INFO WindowsServiceControlManager] LogonAccount after transforming: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, user: SYSTEM, domain: NT AUTHORITY 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z INFO WindowsServiceControlManager] Service name 'vstsagent.----.WIN------------' display name 'VSTS Agent (----.WIN------------)' will be used for service configuration. 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: The service already exists: vstsagent.----.WIN------------, it will be replaced 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Trying to delete service vstsagent.----.WIN------------ 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z ERR  Agent] System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Could not delete service 'vstsagent.----.WIN------------'    
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.NativeWindowsServiceHelper.UninstallService(String serviceName)    
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.WindowsServiceControlManager.ConfigureService(AgentSettings settings, CommandSettings command)    
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.<ConfigureAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.<ExecuteCommand>d__5.MoveNext() 
[2017-09-19 14:35:25Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: Could not delete service 'vstsagent.----.WIN------------'
```

Comment: it seems that we have one free private pipeline.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/licensing/concurrent-pipelines-ts

Comment: Did the two projects deployed in the same release definition or deploy them separately for twice? Can you show the detail tasks and settings (or logs) for your release definitions?

Comment: @Marina - MSFT,  by running script on machine get COULDN'T DELETE SERVICE and in VSTS  got above error

Comment: Can you show the detail logs here?

Comment: @Marina - MSFT, Thank you for tracking. I have added Log from VSTS agent log located in A2 folder(Some Last Lines)

Comment: Agent logs can't detect what's the detail of your problem. Can you show the release logs from VSTS release web page, such as `https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_release?releaseId=releaseID&_a=release-logs`?

Comment: @Marina - MSFT, Thanks again. 
[Error]Unable to deploy to the target 'WIN-XXXX' as the target is offline.

Comment: I get the same thing. Has this been fixed?